# Print values and sum

Tags: javascript

var testArr = [6,3,5,1,2,4]copy
Print Values and Sum

Print each array value and the sum so far
The expected output will be:

Num 6, Sum 6
Num 3, Sum 9
Num 5, Sum 14
Num 1, Sum 15
Num 2, Sum 17
Num 4, Sum 21

How would I write this?

Comment: By first taking the [tour], and reading the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). Right now, you haven't even bothered to properly format your post, so you really want to put in the effort to make sure you have a good post, if you want others to put in the effort to help you (rather than moving on to the next question in their queue)

Answer (score 2):

It can be accomplished using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var testArr = [6, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4];

testArr.reduce((total, num) => {
  console.log(`Num ${num}`);
  total += num;
  console.log(`Sum ${total}`);
  return total;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop to resolve this.

At each stage of the for loop, you run code, going from left to right in the array.

As such, you can just add each number in the array to a total, and print the total each time something is added:

Code below, sections in `//` are comments that do not run but explain what is happening

```
var total =0; // Set the starting sum to 0
var testArr = [6,3,5,1,2,4]; // Get our array
for(var i=0; i< testArr.length; i++){ //i starts at 0, and grows 1 each loop
   total+=testArr[i]; // for testArr[i] each loop, add that number to total
   console.log("Num " = testArr[i]+" Sum:"+total); // Print the current value here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var testArr = [6,3,5,1,2,4];
for(let i = 0; i<testArr.length; i++){
  console.log("Num", testArr[i]);
  let sum = 0;
  for(let j = 0; j<=i; j++) {
    sum += testArr[j];
  }
  console.log("Sum", sum);
}
```